# how to use the svg matrix function to scale an svg back with the correct transform maths

Tags: javascript, svg

If you look at the snippet below, I want to implement zooming on an svg image.

I want it to gracefully zoom in and out.

I am using the  matrix function and I know I can scale back by changing the first and fourth or the matrix or `a` and `d`.

Programmatically I am going to change the transform matrix but I want to keep the svg in the center and not have it move towards the top left or bottom right when zooming in and out.

What is my maths for the last 2 elements of the matrix or `dx` and `dy` to keep my matrix centered as it is zooming?

```html
<svg width="500" height="150">
<rect x="20" y="20" width="50" height="50" transform="matrix(.5,0,0,.5,0,0)" style="fill: #cc3333"></rect>
<rect x="20" y="20" width="50" height="50" transform="matrix(1,0,0,1,0,0)" style="fill: #cc3333"></rect>

<rect x="20" y="20" width="50" height="50" transform="matrix(1.5,0,0,1.5,0,0)" style="fill: #cc3333"></rect>

</svg>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is the way the math works. Because the transform origin for SVG is at the origin of the SVG CANVAS (not the object, unlike CSS) - you first have to translate the shape so its center is at the origin, then you scale it & then you move the center back to its original position.

First - a small note - to convert between the [a, b, c, d, e, f] of an SVG tranform to the "real" underlying matrix, you have to add a third line to the matrix of 0,0,1 in other words, to convert from SVG transform [a, b, c, d, e ,f] to the real matrix, the mapping is:

```
[ a  c  e ]
[ b  d  f ]
[ 0  0  1 ]
```

So - for your first shape - your scale matrix is like so:

```
[ 1.5  0  0 ]
[  0  1.5 0 ]
[  0   0  1 ]
```

and your translate back to the origin matrix (e.g. minus x, minus width/2) is:

```
[  1  0  -45 ]
[  0  1  -45 ]
[  0  0   1 ]
```

Multiply them together (handy tool for [matrix multiplication](http://onlinemschool.com/math/assistance/matrix/multiply/)) and you get this intermediate matrix:

```
[  1.5  0  -45 ]
[  0  1.5  -45 ]
[  0    0   1  ]
```

Next, multiply that intermediate matrix with your "translate back to the original position matrix" which is:

```
[  1  0   45 ]
[  0  1   45 ]
[  0  0   1  ]
```

and the result of the matrix multiplication is:

```
[  1.5  0 -22.5 ] 
[  0  1.5 -22.5 ] 
[  0    0   1   ]
```

tada.

```html
<svg width="500" height="150">
<rect x="20" y="20" width="50" height="50" transform="matrix(1.5,0,0,1.5,-22.5,-22.5)" fill="green"></rect>
<rect x="20" y="20" width="50" height="50" transform="matrix(1,0,0,1,0,0)" fill="blue"></rect>
<rect x="20" y="20" width="50" height="50" transform="matrix(.5,0,0,.5,22.5,22.5)" fill="red"></rect>




</svg>
```

Comment: where does this (minus x, minus width/2) come from when you state and your translate back to the origin matrix (e.g. minus x, minus width/2) is:

Comment: That's the distance between the center of your rectangle and the origin aka. the "x" attribute of your rect is 20, and the width of your rectangle is 50 - so the center of your rectangle is at (20+50/2) = 45. So to translate back to the origin it's -45.

Answer (score 1):

You can play with [`transform-origin`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform-origin) . Values are given by :
`(rec.x + rect.width/2)px` and `(rect.y + rect.height/2)px`

```css
rect{
  transform-origin: 45px 45px;
}
```

```html
<svg width="500" height="150">

<rect x="20" y="20" width="50" height="50" transform="matrix(1.5,0,0,1.5,0,0)" style="fill: #003333"></rect>
<rect x="20" y="20" width="50" height="50" transform="matrix(1,0,0,1,0,0)" style="fill: #cc3333"></rect>
<rect x="20" y="20" width="50" height="50" transform="matrix(.5,0,0,.5,0,0)" style="fill: #0c3003"></rect>

</svg>
```