# Understanding SVG Transform Matrices in Swift App

Tags: ios, swift, svg, affinetransform

I am writing an app that manages images composed of SVG data. I generate the data (drawings) in graphics apps and then export them to SVG.

In doing this, I have to take multiple separate paths which represent brush strokes, and assemble them in a view. This involves a set of transformations, as well as translating the original SVG data into UIBezierPaths.

For one source of drawings, this works perfectly. The different strokes are assembled and animated into the view. But for other drawings, the result is more haphazard.

The culprit seems to be `transform` data in the SVG that one app includes, and the other does not. When I'm dealing with simple point data, my code manages the paths fine, but when I use a file that includes the transform attribute on a containing group, I get only partial results.

Here's what a source drawing looks like that causes the problem:

[image]

and this is how it renders in the iPad app when each shape is imported and transformed:
[image]

I've rendered it as lines to make it clear, but the data is the same. The first image is a png from the original SVG.

It's easy enough to see what's happening: the y origins of each shape are at the negative relative location to their proper location in the original drawing. But this, again, doesn't happen in other files. These problem files like this one, are the ones with the `transform` attribute.

I haven't found any examples of this where any other displacement happens, and I can write a transform that applies only to these files, but I'd like to understand what's actually happening, and perhaps correct it more intelligently.

This is what a typical SVG path looks like in the drawing below:

```
<g transform="matrix(1,0,0,1,-6.34829,501.295)">
   <path d="M92.91,45.528L92.928,[...],45.595L92.696,45.563" style="fill:rgb(130,122,110);"/>
 </g>
```

[I've omitted most of the path data for space]

I understand the idea behind the matrix transformations used in SVG, but have no experience working with this kind of thing. It seems that for the most part these are meant to be parsed by the SVG parser to perform a transformation on the data that follows. I just want to transform the data to be in the proper location, which reduces to the translation values needed.

I can observe from the 7 paths in this drawing that the transform tags are as follows:

```
 <g transform="matrix(1,0,0,1,-6.34829,-11.7843)">
 <g transform="matrix(1,0,0,1,-6.01558,-7.15694)">
 <g transform="matrix(1,0,0,1,-6.34829,-446.518)">
 <g transform="matrix(1,0,0,1,-6.34829,501.295)">
 <g transform="matrix(1,0,0,1,-6.34829,535.999)">
 <g transform="matrix(1,0,0,1,-6.34829,186.983)">
 <g transform="matrix(1,0,0,1,-6.34829,-262.714)">
```

So it seems like a safe bet that the last value is what's doing the transforming. Is it as simple as just grabbing that value and using it to translate the path that follows (prior to all the other transformations in scale and translation that I do to fit the image)? Or is there more to it than that?

If that's the case, I also assume that the first value represents SVG's x transform, and there, the fact that one but only one of the paths varies from the others could be accidental in the drawing process, but I can't actually attribute to any action of mine.

Does anyone have experience with this?

Comment: https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/coords.html#TransformMatrixDefined

Comment: This answer will be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52797338/how-to-use-the-svg-matrix-function-to-scale-an-svg-back-with-the-correct-transfo